# Force ie7 to take jquery.get response as xml despite wrong headers

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I want to consume a web service using jquery's get function. There is no layer in between, since the javascript files are put on the same server as the web service is running on.

My code runs nicely in firefox, but in ie7 the problem arise.
I'm quite certain that i know the answer: xml header states "text/html", and IE7 belives unfortunately that it is true.

So, what can i do to help IE to understand my xml-response as xml? cast/parse?

XML:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<find>
<set_number>005262</set_number>
<no_records>000005611</no_records>
<no_entries>000005611</no_entries>
<session-id>YGSNPECRDEJS4Y3U1A65HMTG9PYPI1UDY1PYNFN2RK4BCDGY2D</session-id>
</find>
```

Code (simplified, the append-stuff takes place in a separate function):

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){      
        $.get(
            "http://server/X?op=find&code=wru&request=arbetsliv&base=rik01",   
            function(data){ 
                $("#wru").append($('no_records',data).text());
            },"xml"
    ); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have dealt with this problem before. The only way I found to solve it was to do a manual ajax call, take the response text, parse it as a DOM document, and then use that.

Comment: I had to do it manually at the time, but I think that jQuery now has an option to force a mime type on the response. Take a look at the 'dataType' option on jQuery.ajax's options parameter.

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options

Comment: I used the information here: http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://server/X?op=find&code=wru&request=biografier&base=rik01",
        success: function(data){
            var xml;
            if ($.browser.msie && typeof data == "string") {
                xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xml.async = false;
                xml.loadXML(data);                
            } else {
                xml = data;
            }
            $("#wsa").append($('no_records',xml).text());
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Just a note:  `$.browser` has been removed from jQuery since this answer was written.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way around this that I've found is to simply convert the result if needed.

```
$.get(
    // all your parameters here
).done(function (data) {
    if (typeof data === 'string') {
        data = jQuery.parseXML(data);
    }
    // data is now a Document for you to use here
});
```